# ErrorException Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, html, laravel

i have this problem that you see from the title , it says undefined variable data
this is my post controller function :

```
public function index()
{
    $data = Post::latest()->paginate(5);

    return view('posts.index', compact('data'))
        ->with('i', (request()->input('page', 1) - 1) * 5);
}
```

and this is my index.blade.php file :

```
@foreach ($data as $key => $value)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ ++$i }}</td>
            <td>{{ $value->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ \Str::limit($value->description, 100) }}</td>
            <td>
                <form action="{{ route('posts.destroy',$value->id) }}" method="POST">
                    <a class="btn btn-info" href="{{ route('posts.show',$value->id) }}">Show</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('posts.edit',$value->id) }}">Edit</a>
                    @csrf
                    @method('DELETE')
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button>
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**this is where i used the data .
but as you see an error comes up .
what can i do ?**

Comment: Pass $data in with().->with($data).

Comment: Your index.blade.php file is not using the function that you mentioned above. Check your route